# FIWARE Orion subscriptions to Node Red plugins

Tags: node-red, fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to create subscriptions using Orion Context Broker and Node-Red plugins.
I want to create custom node red plugins to fit my use case. Is there any sample Node-Red Plugins development repository for subscriptions? Must I use ngsi-proxy or get the result directly from Orion?

My subscriptions provision look like:

```
  "description": "Notify Node Red on Sensor count attribute changes",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": "urn:ngsi-ld:MySensor:001"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "count"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://node-red:1880"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "count"
    ],
    "metadata": ["dateCreated", "dateModified"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is some Node Red stuff related with NGSIv2 out there. You can have a look to https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-fiware_official

Comment: Hi, I use this plugin previously, but it shows only two nodes once it get installed.  From this link I can point to the actual source code, and this is exactly what I need. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Maybe you could even improve the source code (https://github.com/FIWARE/node-red-contrib-FIWARE_official). It's an open source project and I guess the authors would welcome pull request with improvements and additions :)

Comment: Are there any examples on how to configure NodeRED endpoint or NGSI subscription so that it receives notifications of changes in Orion entities? Like the original question was, is it possible to connect directly to Orion (on port 1026) or do you need NGSI proxy in between? If I point Context-Broker Node to Orion port and define fiware-service to be openiot (service that entities should be using) I do not see any traffic on debug view nor at orion logs when sensor updates are published. Am I missing something or how is this thing supposed to work?